# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: when generate SAML signature

Tags: java, rsa, saml, public-key-encryption

I met below error when I use [saml generator](https://github.com/rackerlabs/saml-generator) together with my keystore and certificate, can anyone tell me what goes wrong?

```
    java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at com.rackspace.saml.CertManager.getSigningCredential(CertManager.java:43)
    at com.rackspace.saml.SamlAssertionProducer.createSignature(SamlAssertionProducer.java:228)
    at com.rackspace.saml.SamlAssertionProducer.createSAMLResponse(SamlAssertionProducer.java:39)
    at com.rackspace.saml.Client.getSAMLXML(Client.java:186)
    at com.rackspace.saml.Client.main(Client.java:208)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:95)
    at org.opensaml.common.impl.AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractSAMLObjectMarshaller.java:59)
    at org.opensaml.xml.io.AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall(AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.java:85)
    at com.rackspace.saml.Client.getSAMLXML(Client.java:189)
    at com.rackspace.saml.Client.main(Client.java:208)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup` Do you have this class in classpath?

Comment: @iNan, please check updated error stack

Comment: Try posting it as a issue on his github